# An unknown error occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I hav two textboxes accepting document date range i.e. from and to and when the user enters the date range and clicks search, the ssrs report is fetched displaying the details

the problem is, in first attempt the search results are fetched, but when the user focuses on one of the textbox and press escape twice, and then click on search, an error occurs as follows

---

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.2; MDDRJS)
Timestamp: Tue, 10 Dec 2013 06:35:52 UTC

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 404
Line: 938
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: https://apollo.iqbackoffice.com/Clientweb/ScriptResource.axd?d=xDqhzAnd9ISIOCWdTykrwL2okOsTTc2rLV318oWTO86zRrV9f1ZHzOslOZMRCwi7mFiAZ1N0W7MFdknnrLA3EW02U6NmDhD5euWT5Vux5wMU37YBgR6yCB-Iw31BmVCng4HT6Mw_o1J7aG6OSfXuDA2&t=ffffffffbd2983fc

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 404
Line: 938
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: https://apollo.iqbackoffice.com/Clientweb/ScriptResource.axd?d=xDqhzAnd9ISIOCWdTykrwL2okOsTTc2rLV318oWTO86zRrV9f1ZHzOslOZMRCwi7mFiAZ1N0W7MFdknnrLA3EW02U6NmDhD5euWT5Vux5wMU37YBgR6yCB-Iw31BmVCng4HT6Mw_o1J7aG6OSfXuDA2&t=ffffffffbd2983fc

---

Note:

1. The textboxes are not mandatory fields
2. This is the server side error because on debugging(in IE), it passes the javascript and then gives the error.
3. On localhost I dont get this error, it occurs only on the domain
4. Error only in IE

Comment: debug more and more......

Comment: Are you using ajax control tool kit of asp.net?

Comment: @polin : this is not a valid comment. it makes no sense.

Comment: @SpiderCode Could you get any ideal what the problem is? I mean the representation etc. If you can ,then let me know

Comment: I thought there's something wrong with some of your controls, refer : http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx